# create dynamic number of cards in laravel nova

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-nova

i try to show dynamic numbers of cards in my dashboard how can i do it? in my app each user has few accounts and i need to show the accounts as card how can i define a loop in the return card array ?

i try to define an function in an array with foreach loop

```php
public function cards(Request $request) {
  $accounts = $this-> getAccounts($request->user());
  return [
    function($accounts) {
      foreach($accounts as $account) {
        (new LinkableRouter)->title($account->currency()
             ->first()->symbol.' '.$account
             ->balance)
             ->url('{"name": "index", "params": {"resourceName": "accounts"}}')
             ->subtitle($account->acc);
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

Call to undefined method `Closure::authorize()`

Exception Details

> Type Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Location C:\xampp4\htdocs\newgdi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, assigning function to var is `Closure Object` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)).

When you define annonymos function in your array you set him as Closure object. So basically your function returns array we Closure object (try to `var_dump` his return value where you call it and you will see.

You getting that error as you assuming this function return array of accounts - but no, it return array with one closure element.

I believe you want to change it to something like this (not sure as I don't know your full code):

```
public function cards(Request $request) {
    $accounts = $this->getAccounts($request->user());
    foreach($accounts as $account) {
        $res[] = (new LinkableRouter)->title($account->currency()->first()->symbol . ' ' . $account->balance)
                    ->url('{"name": "index", "params": {"resourceName": "accounts"}}')
                    ->subtitle($account->acc);

    return $res;
}
```